Using Coinbase wallet SDK to send transaction to contract while sending value (eth) results in error
Using Ethers v6 and Coinbase Wallet SDK v4 on localhost:5173 via vite:
I am trying to call a contract and send ETH along with the call, and getting the error:
TypeError: invalid BigNumberish value (argument="%response", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.2)
    at makeError (ethers.js?v=e77ab908:318:15)
    at assert (ethers.js?v=e77ab908:338:11)
    at assertArgument (ethers.js?v=e77ab908:342:3)
    at getBigInt (ethers.js?v=e77ab908:566:3)
    at BrowserProvider.estimateGas (ethers.js?v=e77ab908:17367:12)
    at async ethers.js?v=e77ab908:18570:23
    at async Promise.all (:5173/index 0)
    at async JsonRpcSigner.sendUncheckedTransaction (ethers.js?v=e77ab908:18580:7)
    at async JsonRpcSigner.sendTransaction (ethers.js?v=e77ab908:18587:19)
    at async send (ethers.js?v=e77ab908:14607:16)

I've tried this same call using a MetaMask provider, and no issues. Additionally I can use the Coinbase provider to call any contract functions without sending any ETH value and seems to work fine.
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { CoinbaseWalletSDK } from '@coinbase/wallet-sdk'

const sdk = new CoinbaseWalletSDK({
    appName: 'App Name',
    appChainIds: [1]
})

const provider = await sdk.makeWeb3Provider({ options: 'all' })

// Get accounts / connect
const accounts = await provider.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

// Get a BrowserProvider by using ethers to wrap the Coinbase provider
// Note: Don't need to do this for the MetaMask provider
// But if I don't do it here for Coinbase provider it says that .getSigner is undefined when trying to get a signer
const browserProvider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(provider)

// Get a signer for the contract transaction
const signer = await browserProvider.getSigner()

// Instantiate contract
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer)

const ethSpendAmount = BigInt(10000000)

// Call the contract function and send ETH with it
contract.theContractFunctionToCall(argOne, argTwo, { value: ethSpendAmount })


I debugged it all the way down to where ethers is trying to create a bigInt with the estimateGas Promise:
async estimateGas(_tx) {
    let tx = this._getTransactionRequest(_tx);
    if (isPromise(tx)) {
      tx = await tx;
    }
    return getBigInt(await __privateMethod(this, _AbstractProvider_instances, perform_fn).call(this, {
      method: "estimateGas",
      transaction: tx
    }), "%response");
  }

The seems response it's getting once the promise is resolved is 'undefined'.
If I try to send the transaction using the Coinbase provider, without a value or with a value of 0, the promise does resolve and some BigNumber hex is provided.
If I use the MetaMask provider it resolves normally with a hex.
